# Problems with installing the GeoServer Metadata extension

Tags: geoserver, metadata, windows-10

I have recently tried to install the GeoServer Metadata extension. In the installation instructions indicates that any required configuration must be made in the servlet container, but what changes must be made?

I downloaded the extension from the GeoServer Download Page, the file name is called geoserver-2.17-SNAPSHOT-metadata-plugin.zip, I extracted these files and placed the JARs in WEB-INF/lib, but when I start the service the following message appears

> HTTP 404 Status - Not Found
>   Type Status report
>   message The required resource [/ geoserver] is not available
>   Description The required resource is not available.

I've already done several changes to the code in web.xml file

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>metadata</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.geoserver.community.gs-metadata</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>metadata</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

The installation I have is Windows 10, GeoServer 2.17-SNAPSHOT, Apache-Tomcat/8.5.55, Java jre1.8.0_231.

Answer (score 1):

I installed **SNAPSHOT-metadata-plugin-2017** on my `Microsoft Window 7` machine using `Geoserver 2.17` and `Apache Tomcat 9.0.36`. Before staring please make sure that you are using `JDK 11.0.2` (x64/86 based on your own OS system type). It's supported completely by both `Geoserver 2.17.x` and `Apache Tomcat 9.x.x` as it has been mentioned in [geoserver consideration](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html) and [Apache Tomcat Versions](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html).

Steps:

**1.** Install `JDK 11.0.2` and add `/bin` folder to windows paths. Then define new variable with name `_JAVA_OPTIONS` and value `-Xmx1024m`. Run `java -version` command in command line to see something like following picture:

[image]

**2.** Download `Apache Tomcat 9.x.x` from [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi) and install it. Remember to set the `JDK 11.0.2` path. It will be ask you while you are installing it.

**3.** Download `Geoserver 2.17` in `.war` file via [this link](http://geoserver.org/release/2.17.0/) and copy it into `/webapps` root directory. By restarting the `Apache` service a new folder will be generated which is `Geoserver` application. Now stop `Apache Tomcat` service again.

**4.** Download `geoserver-2.17-SNAPSHOT-metadata-plugin.zip` that is find [here](https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.17.x/community-latest/). Extract and copy containing `.jar` files into `/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib` route.

Although, `Apache Tomcat` will start fine If you go through `http://localhost:xxxx/geoserver/web` link you will be faced with confusing error. I read Apache's log and realized there are some missing java classes and also some mistakes in one of the `pom.xml` files.

**5.** First of all download `jackson-annotations-2.10.1.jar` and `snakeyaml-1.24.jar`. They are available [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.10.1/) and [here](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.24/source-code). Please notice the version. Copy both files
into `/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib`. Following screenshot shows all `.jar` files that `Metadata` plugin requires.

[image]

**6.** Change extension of `gs-metadata-2.17-SNAPSHOT.jar` file to `.rar`, extract it and then go to `<extracted_file_root>/META-INF/maven/org.geoserver.community/gs-metadata` directory. Find `pom.xml` and open it using a proper editor.

[image]

**7.** Inside `pom.xml` find `<!-- progress bar -->` and Add/Edit following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicketstuff-progressbar</artifactId>
    <version>8.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<!--Yaml Parser -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**8.** Save changes, close editor and compress the folder again. Now change its extension to `.jar` and bring it back to the `/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib` directory.

**9.** Start tomcat service and open `Geoserver` application from `http://localhost:xxxx/manager/html`. If you did all correctly, you will see that `Geoserver` starts and you can log in using `admin/geoserver`. You can also find newly added `Metadata` tab in layer publishing menu.

[image]